# definite Integral of power negative one on negative interval

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I try integrating $$\int_{-3}^{-1}\frac{4}{x} \, dx.$$

It's common that integral of power negative one can be expressed as natural logarithm i mean $\int \frac{1}{x} \, dx=\ln x$ but in this case both upper and lower integration limit are negative and this lead into undefined result.

so i try different approaching by using area interpretation of integrand and this give me a rectangle and triangle that have total area of $\frac{16}{3}$ and so i tried check it by riemann sum

$$\int_{-3}^{-1}f(x)\,dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \, \Delta x$$

I took $\Delta x=\frac{2}{n}$ and $xi=\frac{2i}{n}-3$ but i can't procced any further after input $x_i$ into main equation and multiplying things and get :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{4n}{2i-3n} . \frac{2}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{8}{2i-3n}$$

So how i can get past this type (quotient) of summation and got the integral result?

Comment: For $x<0$, an antiderivative of $f(x)=1/x$ is $F(x)=\ln|x|=\ln(-x)$. There is no need to use Riemann sums.

Comment: Thanks , but by any mean i want to know how to do it, i would really appreciate if you can help with it

Comment: Please see Michael Hardy's answer, which is correct.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int \frac 4 x \, dx = 4\ln |x| + \text{constant}, $$
and unfortunately this means
$$
4\ln x + \begin{cases} \text{one constant} & \text{if } x>0, \\ \text{another constant} & \text{if } x<0. \end{cases}
$$
Thus it is "constant" only on each interval separately.

At any rate, note the absolute value sign. Thus you have
$$
\int_{-3}^{-1} \frac 4 x \, dx = 4\ln 1 - 4\ln 3 = -4\ln 3.
$$

Comment: I do not  think it is accurate to say that $\int 4/x\,dx$ contains different constants according to whether $x>0$ or $x<0$. It would be more precise to say that, on any interval not containing the origin, the indefinite integral of $f(x)=4/x$ is $F(x)=4\ln|x|+C$, with an equally arbitrary constant in any case.

Comment: @GReyes : As long as we're only taking about a function of a real variable, not of a complex variable or anything else, the set of all antiderivatives is just the set of piecewise defined functions that I identified here.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you define things. I am used to defining the concept on a given interval. On the other hand, I do not find very useful the concept of "antiderivative" on the whole domain", since, for example, if the function has a singularity you cannot tie the definite integral to the variation of the antiderivative. It seems to me a useless generalization. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @GReyes : You're probably right about how things would be done in an ideal world, but unfortunately we live in world where things like Stewart's textbooks are the standard.

Comment: Agreed. I have been using Stewart’s book and similar ones for over 15 years for my teaching. Shallow, focused on procedures rather than on concepts. And this after so many beautiful textbooks written in half a century ago (Spivak, Apóstol, Lang..) . Students would learn better Calculus reading Euler..

Comment: @GReyes : I agree with you on deploring the focus on procedures rather than on concepts. But Spivak is utterly unsuitable for the vast masses of students that the system encourages to take calculus. And anyone who's been awake at any time in the past 50 years knows that the solution is NOT to try to get those teeming masses ready for Spivak, but rather to teach them math courses suitable for students whose interests are in other things that mathematics (if they are to be taught math at all).